# Why is my DriveApp.getFileById call stalling?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a file via the Google MailApp in Apps script and want to attach a PDF from my drive. The attached code then seems to be stalling, besides being in a try/catch block.

```
   var attachment = []; 
   try {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xyz")
      attachment.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF))
   }  catch (e)  {
      Logger.log(e.message)
   }
```

The debugger / runner never leaves the getFileByID. Permissions are set on the console.

//Update: The stackdriver logs show:

```
Error   Exceeded maximum execution time
```

To add, I am on a G-Suite enterprise account.

Comment: Are you passing a valid file ID?

Comment: Does it run without using the debugger?

Comment: Valid file ID, same behaviour without the debugger.

Comment: Is this is Web App shared with someone?  Check the stackdriver logging after running the code.  View menu, stackdriver logging.  Check the status column.  Click the down arrow to expand the information.

Comment: Is the file inside a Shared Drive? Can you retrieve it using the [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)?

Comment: Stack Driver log added. Shared Drive and My Drive tried - no difference. I will try the API call later